# Gibt es Vorschläge zur Reform der Genusbezeichnungen?

Tags: gender, terminology

Wenn man das Genussystem anschaut, gibt es in den seltensten Fällen eine Kongruenz mit einem biologischen Geschlecht. Es gibt aber eine sehr starke Kongruenz zwischen Genus und bestimmten Wortbildungen, also z. B. Diminutiv, Kollektivbildungen oder substantivierte Verben sind sächlich oder -ung, -heit, -keit sind weiblich.
Bei produktiven Bildungen ist es offensichtlich, für untergegangene Bildungen ist es sprachwissenschaftlich häufig noch nachvollziehbar. Es ist also eine Systematik vorhanden, die aber in den seltensten Fällen etwas mit Mann/Frau/Sache zu tun hat. Weiterhin fehlt eine ordentliche Einordnung von substantivierten Partizipien oder Adjektiven, deren Genus erst durch den Artikel/Zusammenhang bestimmt wird.

Hat es schon ernsthafte Vorschläge gegeben, das System in der Grammatiklehre zu reformieren, d. h. beispielsweise abstrakt von "Nomenklasse I-IV" zu sprechen?

Edit: Es geht *nicht* darum, die Genera in der *Sprache* abzuschaffen, à la "wir sagen ab jetzt die Mann, die Frau, die Telefon". Es geht darum, ob je darüber nachgedacht oder es vorgeschlagen wurde, die Kategorien maskulin, feminin, neutral aufzugeben.

Comment: Nach Lesen des Titels („Reform des Genussystems“) hatte ich eine sehr andere Frage erwartet.

Comment: Lang lebe die glorreiche Rechschreibreform :)

Comment: @KilianFoth: Da geht es nicht um die Rechtschreibung, sondern um etwas, das die gesprochene Sprache betrifft und mit dem Schreiben nichts zu tun hat. Die Rechtschreibung ist nur ein Satz von Regeln, die vorgeben, wie Sprache in Schrift umzuwandeln ist. Eine Reform des Genus-Systems würde diese Regeln nicht berühren, sondern würde versuchen, die Sprache selbst zu verändern. (Das Wort *Sprache* kommt nicht von *schreiben*, sondern von *sprechen*!)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Nein, nein, die Rechtschreibreform soll hochleben, weil sie endlich den Unterschied zwischen Genusssystemen und Genussystemen erlaubt.

Comment: @KilianFoth: Woher kommt dein Glaube, ich hätte etwas gegen die Rechtschreibreform? Das Gegenteil ist der Fall, ich befürworte sie. Ich wollte dich nur darauf hinweisen, dass die hier gestellte Frage nichts mit Rechtschreibung zu tun hat. (Wohl aber mit einer Reform)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich denke, du missverstehst, dass sich [Kilians Kommentar](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26769/gibt-es-vorschl%c3%a4ge-zur-reform-des-genussystems#comment64781_26769) nicht auf die Frage bezieht, sondern auf [chirlus Kommentar](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26769/gibt-es-vorschl%c3%a4ge-zur-reform-des-genussystems#comment64721_26769) (in der Interpretation, dass chirlu eine Reform eines Genuss-Systems statt eines Genus-Systems (Getrenntschreibung hier zur Verdeutlichung) erwartet hatte).

Comment: @O.R. Mapper: Ja, wobei diese Interpretation falsch ist. Ich habe inzwischen [weiter unten](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26769/gibt-es-vorschl%c3%a4ge-zur-reform-der-genusbezeichnungen#comment64830_26797) ausgeführt, was ich eigentlich meinte (nicht Änderung des Genus-Systems, sondern Änderung der Art, wie man das System beschreibt).

Comment: @chirlu: Ja. Insgesamt stehen wohl drei Interpretationen (z.B. A, B, C) im Raum, und während du z.B. den Unterschied zwischen A/B meintest, wurde dein Kommentar ggf. je nach Lesart wegen Zustimmung zum Unterschied A/B oder A/C aufgewertet, da auch der Kommentar sich auf verschiedene Weise interpretieren ließ ;) Schöne Verwirrung ;)

Comment: @KilianFoth Der Unterschied zwischen einem *Genußsystem* und einem *Genussystem* ist auch in vorreformatorischer Orthographie klar (außer für Schweizer).

Comment: @Veredomon: Selbst der Nachtrag ist noch missverständlich formuliert. Die Kategorien aufzugeben würde bedeuten, dass man maskuline, feminine und neutrale Wörter alle gleich behandelt, also z.B. für alle dieselben Artikel verwendet. Man sollte schon klar zwischen einer Sprache und ihrer Beschreibung unterscheiden. Die Terminologie wird aus gutem Grund nicht geändert, denn dann hätte man nicht nur einen historischen Bruch, sondern würde nah verwandte Phänomene in verschiedenen Sprachen ohne Not unterschiedlich benennen.

Comment: Wenn man z.B. die Wörter Maskulinum/Femininum/Neutrum durch rot/grün/blau ersetzen würde, müsste man ja noch dazusagen, dass, mit zunehmender Tendenz, für Männer tendenziell die roten Personalpronomen verwendet werden und für Frauen tendenziell die grünen. (Beispiel: "Das Mädchen sitzt auf der Bank. Dann steht sie auf.") Auch die Beziehungen zu Sprachen mit ausschließlich natürlichem Geschlecht würden dann plötzlich kompliziert erscheinen.

Comment: @HansAdler und Rest: Ich verstehe nicht, was an der Frage so ungewöhnlich sein soll. Die Nomenklatur wurde öfter geändert oder diskutiert, siehe z. B. Präsensperfekt, Präteritumperfekt und Futurperfekt statt Perfekt, Plusquamperfekt und Futur II. Den Sinn, dies zu tun, können wir ja anheimgestellt lassen - mich interessiert primär, ob das mal von irgendjemandem in einem sprachwissenschaftlichen Rahmen vorgeschlagen/diskutiert wurde.

Comment: @Veredomon: Ich vermute, die Antwort ist *nein*, aber um die zu geben, müsste man die gesamte sprachwissenschaftliche Literatur kennen. Diese Kategorien gehen ja schon auf die klassische griechische und römische Grammatik zurück. Maskulin und feminin bezeichnen ja Kategorien, die schon im Proto-Indoeuropäischen existiert haben. Auch das Neutrum existiert in zahlreichen europäischen Sprachen. Es hätte nicht viel Sinn, das nur für eine Sprache umzubenennen - und wenn man es für alle tut, müsste es halt auch zum Englischen passen, wo die etablierte Nomenklatur aber gerade mal deskriptiv ist.

Answer (score 4):

**R, S, E**

Tatsächlich wecken die klassischen aus der lateinisch-griechischen Grammatiktradition stammenden Begriffe *Maskulinum*, *Femininum* (zusammen *Utrum*) und *Neutrum* (wörtlich: ‚keins von beiden‘) und insbesondere ihre Übersetzungen *männlich*, *weiblich* und *sächlich* in der Schulgrammatik eine gewisse Erwartungshaltung an die Genus-Sexus-Kongruenz, die nur partiell eingehalten wird. Außerdem verhält sich der der Plural (abgesehen von der Stammänderung bei vielen Substantiven) bzgl. der Flexion wie eine weitere Nominalklasse, die weitgehend dem Femininum entspricht, so wie Neutrum und Maskulinum einander sehr gleichen. Eisenberg (z.B. in *Das Wort*) u.a. fassen daher bei der Synkretismusanalyse der Flexion gelegentlich Maskulinum und Neutrum zum Standardgenus (**Std.**) sowie Femininum und Plural zum Non-/Nichtstandardgenus (**Nstd.**) zusammen.

Das Genus ist eine Einheitenkategorie der Substantive, aber eine Paradigmenkategorie seiner Begleiter, Verweiser und Ersetzer. Das heißt, jedes Substantiv hat ein Genus, aber man sieht es einen Wortformen normalerweise nicht an – auch den Kasus häufig und den Numerus manchmal nicht. Normalerweise stellt aber mindestens ein kongruenter Begleiter, üblicherweise der erste/linkeste, im Zusammenspiel mit der Position der Phrase im Satz die KNG-Verhältnisse klar.

Darum wäre es nicht unlogisch, die Flexionsmorpheme der Artikel, Adjektive und Pronomen zur Benennung der Genera heranzuziehen.
Tatsächlich habe schon von **R-, S- und E-Genus** oder ***der*-, *das*- und *die*-Geschlecht** gelesen. Speziell erinnere ich mich an ein DaF-Blog, finde es aber gerade nicht wieder, und weiß nicht, ob diese Bezeichnungen im Deutschunterricht für Fremdsprachler verbreitet(er) sind.

Im Übrigen passt das auch zur Bezeichnung der Kasus Nominativ, Akkusativ, Dativ und Genitiv als *wer-, wen-, wem*- und *wes*-Fälle, die man entsprechend auf R, N, M und S verkürzen könnte.

PS: Da jedes substantivische Derivationsmorphem (z.B. *-ung, -ling, -in, -tum, -nis, -er, -keit, -heit, -ei; -and, -ant, -ent, -or, -ör, -öse, -at, -ur, -ium, -ion, -ist, -ismus …*) ein fixes Genus trägt und das letzte/rechteste Element stets das Gesamtgeschlecht eines komplexen Wortes bestimmt, ist das Genus vieler „abgeleiteter“ bzw. aller „zusammengesetzter“ Substantive prinzipiell auch ohne Begleiter erkennbar, auch wenn manche auf den ersten Blick gleich aussehen.

Comment: Ist 'er' in Messer, Toaster, Hammer, Bruder ein substantivisches Derivationsmorphem aber in Mutter, Butter, Schwester nicht?

Comment: @userunknown In _Mut**ter**_ und _Schwes**ter**_ steckt dasselbe Morphem {_-der, -ter_} wie in _Va**ter**_, _Bru**der**_, _Toch**ter**_ und wohl auch _Vet**ter**_. Es ist in vielen indoeuropäischen Sprachen zu finden, aber kein klassisches Derivationsmorphem – die hypothetischen Stämme kommen anderweitig nicht vor. _+er_ ist Morph verschiedener Morpheme, und dient daher nicht nur zur „Agentis“-Substantivierung vor allem von Verbstämmen (_mess+en_ → _der Mess+er_). In _Hammer_ und _Butter_ ist _-er_ offenbar Teil des Stammes, vgl. _hämmer+n_ und _butter+n_.

Comment: Daraus würde ich folgern, dass das Genus nur für Experten bestimmbar ist.

Comment: Was soll das Getrolle, @userunknown? Natürlich laufen insbesondere einfache Endungen wie Schwa (_-e_) und silbische Sonoranten (_-er, -el, -en, -em, -es_) stets Gefahr, in Derivation und Flexion sowie Stämmen mehrfach verwendet zu werden, was die Analyse erschwert. Sehr viele Ableitungssuffixe sind trotzdem offensichtlich und geschlechtlich eindeutig, außerdem behalten sie ihre Flexion nach Kasus und Numerus stets bei. Nichtsdestotrotz offenbart ein isoliertes Substantiv sein Genus im Allgemeinen nicht – Ableitungen sind speziell. Darum lehrt DAF sie mit eindeutigem Begleiter: _der, die, das_.

Comment: Inwiefern Getrolle? Ich habe nachgefragt, weil eine Aussage von Dir von mir so verstanden wurde, dass sie im Widerspruch zu dem stand, was ich bislang gelernt habe; dass das Genus eines Wortes meist bestimmbar sei. Jetzt hast Du es näher ausgeführt und bestätigst, dass dies im Allgemeinen nicht so ist. Nimm Kritik bitte nicht persönlich.

Answer (score 1):

In dem Buch "Gender" von Greville Corbett wird der Begriff recht grundlegend definiert:

> All this means that the determining criterion of gender is agreement; this the way in which the genders are 'reflected in the behavior of associated words' in Hockett's definition given earlier. Saying that a language has three genders implies that there are three classes of nouns which can be distinguished syntactically by the agreements they take.

Dies ist insofern interessant, dass der traditionelle Begriff "Genus" als gleichbedeutend zu einem moderneren, abstrakteren Begriff "Wortklasse" angesehen wird. Zudem wird Genus/Wortklasse nicht über eine bestimmte semantische Funktion definiert, sondern über die schlichte Tatsache, dass in einer Sprache bestimmte Wörter mit Substantiven syntaktisch kongruieren.

Es wäre insofern tatsächlich gerechtfertigt, sich von der Einteilung männlich, weiblich, sächlich zu verabschieden und abstrakt von z. B. Wortklasse I, II und III zu sprechen.

Comment: Es wäre dann keinem erklärbar, warum in der Grundschule den Kindern beigebracht werden würde, dass "der Mann" nicht mehr männlich ist, sondern Wortklasse I. Es ist nun mal so, dass sich der Genus aller abstrakten Begriffe in das Schema echter Geschlechter einordnet und nicht umgekehrt.

Comment: Ach, @falkb, was ist denn bitte an dem Löffel männlich und an der Gabel weiblich? Oder, das berühmte Totschlagargument: Dass das Mädchen sächlich ist, will doch niemandem so recht einleuchten. Wenn man die Geschichte der Genera zurückgeht, wie es [Belles Lettres](http://www.belleslettres.eu/artikel/genus-gendersprech.php) getan hat, ist die eigentliche Frage, wieso es nicht ***der** Frau* heißt.

Comment: @falkb: Das Weib ist sächlich, die Sache ist weiblich. :) Es ist nun mal nicht so, wie Du behauptest, sondern umgekehrt.

Comment: Ihr reitet auf dem "das" herum, was hier die einzige Ausnahme ist, aber sich ganz trivial ethymologisch erklären lässt, wie z.B. "das Mädchen" von der Verkleinerungsform von "die Magd" abstammt. Nochmal: Das Volk braucht greifbare Begriffe und nicht so etwas wie "Wortklasse I".

Comment: @falkb: Also bitte. Eine Grammatiklehre, die Unsäglichkeiten wie Partizip II oder Futur II beinhaltet, möge nicht "greifbar" genannt werden. Die m/f/n-Lehre hingegen gibt eine Greifbarkeit vor, die nicht gegeben ist, da die Genus/Sexus-Kongruenz unter 10% liegt.

Answer (score -5):

Hans Adler hat in [seiner Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/26797/1487) bereits ausführlich beschrieben, welche Versuche es in dieser Richtung in der Vergangenheit gab. Ich möchte hier nur ergänzen, dass sich keiner dieser Versuche in der Praxis durchsetzen konnte, und dass dieses Schicksal unausweichlich auch allen zukünftigen derartigen Reformversuchen blühen wird.

Deutsch wird von knapp 100 Millionen Menschen als Muttersprache gesprochen. Jeder Versuch, per Reform etwas am Genus-System der deutschen Sprache zu ändern würde bedeuten, dass 100 Millionen Menschen ihre eigene Muttersprache neu lernen müssten. Versuche, »das Weib« und »das Mädchen« durch »die Weib« und »die Mädchen« zu ersetzen, sind zum Scheitern verdammt solange Kinder ihre Muttersprache von Eltern, Großeltern, Freunden usw. lernen, die selbst ihre Sprache von deren Vorfahren, Nachbarn, Freunden und Arbeitskollegen gelernt haben.

Kein Mensch lernt seine Muttersprache in einer Schule oder von einer anderen Institution, die vorgeben könnte, welche Substantive welches Geschlecht zu haben haben. In der Schule lernt man »nur« einen theoretischen Unterbau (die Regeln der Grammatik), der zur tatsächlichen Benutzung der gesprochenen Sprache im Alltag nicht notwendig ist. Die eigene Muttersprache sprechen kann jeder Mensch  schon vor seinem ersten Schultag, also bevor man auch nur den geringsten Kontakt mit Grammatik-Regeln hatte. (Die wenigen Menschen, die aufgrund einer Erkrankung nicht dazu in der Lage sind, im Kindesalter eine Sprache zu erlernen, sollen hier nicht das Thema sein.)

Man lernt in der Schule auch, die gesprochene Sprache in Form von Schrift festzuhalten, wozu Regeln gelernt werden müssen, die eine genormte Abbildung von Sprache zu Schrift ermöglichen, um später wieder auf eine möglichst genormte Weise aus der Schrift das gesprochene Wort rekonstruieren zu können.

Aber diese Verschriftlichung ist der ursprünglichen Funktion der Sprache untergeordnet. Daher ist es relativ einfach, per Reform diese Rechtschreibregeln zu vereinheitlichen (1876) oder zu verändern (1901, 1996), wobei auch jede dieser drei Reformen bekanntermaßen großen Widerstand in der Bevölkerung hervorgerufen hat.

Eine Reform am eigentlichen Kern der Sprache, also nicht an den Regeln zur Verschriftlichung, sondern an jenem Teil der Sprache, der sich im gesprochenen Wort widerspiegelt, ist unmöglich per Erlass oder sonstige Einflussnahme eines Gremiums durchführbar. Und das schon gar nicht bei einem Bestandteil der Sprache, der eine grundlegende Eigenschaft einer der wichtigsten Wortarten betrifft.

Fazit:

Probiert wird es hie und da, aber diese Versuche finden im Elfenbeinturm, fern von jeder Realität, statt und werden von der breiten Bevölkerung völlig ignoriert. Und jede Behörde oder Institution, die theoretisch in der Lage wäre, solche Reformvorschläge zu verbreiten, wird sich tunlichst hüten, das zu tun, weil sie sich damit sofort und unweigerlich den Zorn der Bevölkerung ob der als unbotmäßig empfundenen Bevormundung zuziehen würde.

Comment: Wie schon Hans’ Antwort geht auch diese an der Frage vorbei.